# Why is the project "Rename..." button grayed out?

Tags: windows-10, rider

I wanted to rename some projects in `Rider` but the `Rename...` button in the context menu is inactive. What am I doing wrong? The shortcut `Ctrl+R,R` also doesn't work. It's an ASP.NET Core project and I'm using Rider that has just been released. The solution was previously created by Visual Studio 2017 and I added other projects with Rider but even those new projects cannot be renamed. It works however on files but not on projects or solution folders.

[image: rider-rename-disabled]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it was not implemented: 
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-1224

Comment: Unbelievable :-O